# Deepspeed on dolly-7B not using all GPUs while inferencing

Tags: pytorch, inference, multi-gpu, large-language-model

I followed their official [tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeed/blob/master/docs/_tutorials/inference-tutorial.md) for inferencing using Deepspeed

However, I keep getting CUDA OOM error. When I check GPU usage, it seems, instead of consuming 4 available 24Gi GPUs, it is using single GPU.
To reproduce code:

```
generator = pipeline(model="databricks/dolly-v2-7b", torch_dtype=torch.float, trust_remote_code=True)
generator.model = deepspeed.init_inference(generator.model,
                                           mp_size=world_size,
                                           dtype=torch.float,
                                           replace_with_kernel_inject=True)
```

I run the script as `deepspeed --num_gpus 4 scipt.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
mp_size = int(os.environ["LOCAL_RANK"])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.